# Custom HorizontalScrollView management - enable/disable scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, horizontalscrollview

I'm trying to have a vertical and horizontal scroll at the same time but some time I don't need to active this horizontal scroll.

So I would like to have a custom horizontal view component where I could manage the horizontal scrolling as I want.

So I've implemented this custom horizontal scroll class:

```
public class CustomHorizontalScroll extends ScrollView {

    private boolean enableScrolling = true;

    public boolean isEnableScrolling() {
        return enableScrolling;
    }

    public void setEnableScrolling(boolean enableScrolling) {
        this.enableScrolling = enableScrolling;
    }

    public CustomHorizontalScroll(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomHorizontalScroll(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomHorizontalScroll(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        if (isEnableScrolling()) {
            return super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (isEnableScrolling()) {
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In my activity I can enable or disable scroll like that:

```
horizontalScrollView = (CustomHorizontalScroll) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_scroll_view);
horizontalScrollView.setEnableScrolling(true); // try first to set as enable by default to see if it works
```

But at this point the scroll is always blocked even if I pass like in this example above 'true'.

Here my layout code with vertical and horizontal scroll:

```
<!-- Vertical scroll -->
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/staffList_scrollview"
        android:layout_width="950dp"
        android:layout_height="555dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <!-- Horizontal scroll -->
        <com.myPackage.CustomHorizontalScroll
            android:id="@+id/horizontal_scroll_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                ....
            </RelativeLayout>
       </com.myPackage.CustomHorizontalScroll>

</ScrollView>
```

What could be my problem here ? I would like to be able to disable and enable this horizontal scroll. But at the moment with this custom horizontal class, this scroll is always disable I can turn it enable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is two problems. First, extends to ScrollView instead HorizontalScrollView.

Second, assign a fixed width to vertical scroll.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/staffList_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="950dp"
    android:layout_height="555dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
```

If you change by this it should works

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/staffList_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="555dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
```

Test with these changes and tell me if it works. Greetings.

Comment: The match_parent doesn't suit to my needs but actually yea I didn't notice this wrong extends... my bad. Thank you for that.